# Can I achieve orthographic lighting in Blender?

Tags: lighting

I define orthographic lighting as a single light source that cast a shadow at the same angle no matter where the shape is? Either in front or behind the lamp shading is at the same angle.

Conditions: Blender render, toon shading (non gradient shading), and you cannot node any objects only the lamp.

Can this be done?

Comment: Are not describing exactly what a Sun lamp does?

Comment: @Duarte Farrajota Ramos Yes for the lighting but sun mode might not be compatible with the conditions I have set.

Comment: Which ones exactly does it violate?

Answer (score 2):

Use a Sun Lamp

Form the [blender manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/blender_render/lighting/lamps/sun/introduction.html):

> A Sun lamp provides light of constant intensity emitted in a single direction.
>
> This direction can be changed by rotating the Sun lamp, like any other object, but because the light is emitted in a constant direction, the location of a Sun lamp does not affect the rendered result (unless you use the “sky & atmosphere” option).

Comment: Stupidly posed question = duh answer